# How to fix Cordova app crashing on iOS 16.1?

Tags: ios, swift, cordova

I'm developing a Cordova application for iOS platform. It's crashing on `iOS 16.1` only.

I'm adding Cordova `CDViewController` as a subview on a view controller like below.

```swift
//SampleViewController is SubClass of CDVViewcontroller.
if let tempWidgetVC =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SampleController") as? SampleController {
            tempWidgetVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 135, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height - 150)
             self.view.addSubview(tempWidgetVC.webView)
}
```

Crash is happening when I'm using the above code after API call while the same thing is working in `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`.

CrashLog:

> - thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffffffffffff0) frame #0:
>   0x0000000117237c04
>   WebKit`WebKit::WebUserContentControllerProxy::removeUserMessageHandlerForName(WTF::String const&, API::ContentWorld&) + 804 frame #1: 0x0000000116ed2a54 WebKit`-[WKUserContentController removeScriptMessageHandlerForName:] +
>   52 frame #2: 0x0000000111e350fe
>   BlackBerryDynamics`___lldb_unnamed_symbol7713 + 267 frame #3: 0x000000011719ab7f WebKit`WebKit::WebProcessPool::~WebProcessPool() +
>   2569 frame #4: 0x0000000116ecf9a1 WebKit`-[WKProcessPool dealloc] + 48 frame #5: 0x00007ff80004b6b1 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_object::sidetable_release(bool, bool) + 203 frame
>   #6: 0x00000001171a4b43 WebKit`WebKit::WebProcessProxy::~WebProcessProxy() + 2389 frame #7: 0x00000001171a4c4e WebKit`WebKit::WebProcessProxy::~WebProcessProxy()
>
> - 14 frame #8: 0x0000000116cdf39d WebKit`WTF::ThreadSafeRefCounted<WebKit::AuxiliaryProcessProxy, (WTF::DestructionThread)2>::deref() const + 67 frame #9: 0x00000001171afb38 WebKit`WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<WebKit::WebPageProxy::close()::$_13,
>   void>::~CallableWrapper() + 136 frame #10: 0x00000001140878f8
>   JavaScriptCore`WTF::RunLoop::performWork() + 440 frame #11: 0x00000001140881da JavaScriptCore`WTF::RunLoop::performWork(void*) +
>   26 frame #12: 0x00007ff800387035
>   CoreFoundation`**CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION**
> - 17 frame #13: 0x00007ff800386f74 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 157 frame #14: 0x00007ff800386771 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 212 frame #15:
>   0x00007ff800380e73 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 927 frame #16: 0x00007ff8003806f7 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560 frame
>   #17: 0x00007ff809c5c28a GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 139 frame #18: 0x000000011f36562b UIKitCore`-[UIApplication _run] + 994 frame #19: 0x000000011f36a547 UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 123 frame #20: 0x00000001109e2c72 libswiftUIKit.dylib`UIKit.UIApplicationMain(Swift.Int32,
>   Swift.Optional<Swift.UnsafeMutablePointer<Swift.UnsafeMutablePointer<Swift.Int8>>>,
>   Swift.Optional<Swift.String>, Swift.Optional<Swift.String>) ->
>   Swift.Int32 + 98 frame #21: 0x000000010f805c55 OCPMobile`main
>   [inlined] generic specialization <App.AppDelegate> of static
>   __C.UIApplicationDelegate.main() -> () at UserDefaultsHelper.swift:0 [opt]
>
> - frame #22: 0x000000010f805c05 OCPMobile`main [inlined] static OCPMobile.AppDelegate.$main() -> () at <compiler-generated>:11:1 [opt] frame #23: 0x000000010f805bf4 OCPMobile`main at
>   UserDefaultsHelper.swift:0 [opt] frame #24: 0x000000010ffeb2bf
>   dyld_sim`start_sim + 10 frame #25: 0x0000000113f8852e dyld`start + 462

Comment: That's not a crash log. That's part of the current stack trace. Copy and paste the error shown in the console. Also click on the yellow warning triangle and see what that has to say.

Comment: @HangarRash yellow warning sign "Current thread cause crash".
Added crash log with question itslef, Can you please check now ?